# How to move from Title box to Content box without mouse?

Tags: powerpoint

I create a new slide (`Ctrl+m`).
The layout by default is Title + Content.
I edit the title slide and now want to move to the content textbox.
How can I do this without my mouse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nutshell answer:

- Hit ESC, then TAB key.

Short answer:

1. After typing your text into the Title placeholder, hit ESC to exit editing.
2. Then hit the TAB key to move to the next object. (If that is not the Content placeholder, continue hitting TAB until the desired object is selected.)
3. Start typing to enter your text.

Extended answer:

1. Hit Ctrl+m to create a new slide that uses the same Layout as the current one.
2. Hit the TAB key to go to the first object on the slide. (This is the back-most object on your slide; the one on the bottom in the    Selection Pane list.  If the designer of the Layout did a good job, this is the Title placeholder. If not, keep hitting TAB until the desired object is selected.)
3. Start typing your text. (If you edit an existing slide and there is already text contained in the shape, simply starting to type will append text at the end. If you want to replace the existing text, hit the return/enter key before starting to type. That will select all contained text, so it will be overwritten when you start typing.)
4. When finished entering your text, hit the ESC button (to exit edit mode and have the actual shape selected), and hit the TAB key to go to the next object – i.e. the second-lowest one.  (Again, if the designer did a good job, this will be your Content placeholder. If not, continue hitting TAB.)
5. Go to step 3 to continue with the next object.

Answer (score 1):

After typing the title text, press CTRL + M to put the cursor in the content placeholder.